# Как обрезать область у блока?

Tags: html, css

Помогите обрезать блок таким образом как показано на скриншоте (красное нужно сделать прозрачным).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: CSS Clip-Path не ?

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 0):

как уже сказали выше `clip-path`, либо... можно немножко извратиться:

```css
body{background: lightgreen;}
#x{
background: linear-gradient(285deg, transparent 20px 21px, pink 21px 22px, pink);
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<p id='x'>
aaaa<br>
aaaa<br>
aaaa<br>
aaaa<br>
</p>
```